# A set is the union of elements of a subset of the power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was given this exercise:
Let $X\neq \varnothing$ and $\mathcal{A}\subset P(X)$. Then $A\subset X$ is the union of elements of $\mathcal{A}$ if and only if for all $x\in A$, there exists some $B\in\mathcal{A}$ such that
$x\in B\subset A$.

I did the following
$\Rightarrow$ If $A\subset X$ is the union of elements of $\mathcal{A}$. Let $\left\lbrace M_i\right\rbrace_{i\in\Lambda}$ be the elements of $\mathcal{A}$, so
$$A=\bigcup_{i\in\widetilde{\Lambda}\subset\Lambda}M_i.$$
Then, let $x\in A$, for definition of generalized union, there exists $j\in\widetilde{\Lambda}$ s.t $x\in M_j$ and $M_j \in \mathcal{A}$, then
$$x\in M_j\subset \bigcup_{i\in\widetilde{\Lambda}\subset\Lambda}M_i=A,$$ then $x\in M_j\subset A.$

My questions are: I'm not sure if in the statement, $A$ is the union of all elements of $\mathcal{A}$ or just a subset of it (I wrote this side of the the proof keeping in mind this last option), and I want to know all is well written, specially with the notation I used.
Thanks :)

Comment: When you say $\subset$, do you mean $\subseteq$ or $\subsetneq$?

Comment: Your proof is correct. Try the converse part now.

Comment: @Arthur my teacher makes no difference between $\subset$ and $\subseteq$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you! So, in the statement, $A$ can be referred as the union of all elements or a subset of $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: @AHexe Then I disagree with your teacher. Presumably they make a difference between $<$ and $\leq$. The subset symbol really, really ought to work the same way. But unfortunately one cannot say your teacher is wrong, because their convention is sadly prevalent.

Comment: @Arthur it's a little bit confusing the conventions of $\subset$, $\subseteq$ and $\not\subseteq$  xD

Comment: The use of the word 'the' is important. When they say $A$ is the union of elements of $\mathcal A$ it means you are taking the union of all elements of  $\mathcal A$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy oh, now I see it, thanks for your explanation :D

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I would say "of **the** elements of $\mathcal A$" is more correct if you want to force the union to use all elements of $\mathcal A$. I would read the given problem statement as "Then $A\subseteq X$ is the union of (some) elements of $\mathcal A$ iff ..."